# gsl::fail_fast not found in the namespace

Tags: c++, c++17, guideline-support-library

In this simple use of C++ contracts, I get the `error: no type named 'fail_fast' in namespace 'gsl'`. Will try block throw the `fast_fail` exception or some other exception?

```
#define GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION
#include <gsl/gsl>
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
    try {
        Expects(false);
    }
    catch(const gsl::fail_fast &e) {
        std::cout << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with gsl to post an answer, but surely the `#define` needs to come before including the header for it to have any effect?

Comment: @GManNickG That's right. Thanks

Comment: Was that a solution to your issue? If so, leave the question as it was and post a self-answer instead.

Comment: Header file gsl_assert.h only defines gsl::fail_fast exception with GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION defined. So it compiles now?

Comment: @GManNickG, I had GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION defined before the includes from the beginning. I misplaced it here in the post at first. Still it doesn't compile. I guess I could post it on GSL Github as an "issue"?

Comment: What a terrible name for the library, I just realized now that "Guidelines Support Library" clash with "GNU Scientific Library"!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/issues/267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` and `gsl::fast_fail` were removed from the Microsoft GSL starting with [release v3.0.0](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/releases/tag/v3.0.0). All contract violations result in a call to `std::terminate` unless you are building in kernel mode for MSVC where it invokes `__fastfail`.

> Header file gsl_assert.h only defines gsl::fail_fast exception with GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION defined. So it compiles now? – Serve Laurijssen

There was a period of time where `gsl::fast_fail` was defined only when `GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` was defined, however that was identified in [#267](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/issues/267) and subsequently fixed in [#268](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/pull/268).